# Heroku Deployment Error - push failed to compile Node.js app

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, heroku

I am getting this error while pushing my node.js project to heroku. I have added **"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install npm && run build"* in my package.json as well. I have also installed node-gyp and added ** "proxy": "http://localhost:5000" ** in the package.json file. What can I do apart from that?

```
remote:        > node-addon-api@3.2.1 install /tmp/build_9d38a5ac/server/node_modules/node-addon-api
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild
remote:
remote:        gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /tmp/build_9d38a5ac/server/node_modules/node-addon-api) while trying to load binding.gyp      
remote:        gyp ERR! configure error
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_9d38a5ac/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1103-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_9d38a5ac/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_9d38a5ac/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_9d38a5ac/server/node_modules/node-addon-api
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v8.1.2
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
remote:        
remote:        > bcrypt@5.0.1 install /tmp/build_9d38a5ac/server/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION 
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack /tmp/build_9d38a5ac/server/node_modules/make-dir/index.js:31
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack          ...defaults,
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack          ^^^
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_9d38a5ac/server/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/install.js:13:17)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1103-aws
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_9d38a5ac/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_9d38a5ac/server/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_9d38a5ac/server/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.1.2
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 7
remote:        npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 7
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.1 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.kyEH8/_logs/2022-06-01T13_22_35_382Z-debug.log
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 7
remote:        npm ERR! programming-thoughts@1.0.0 install: `cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 7
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the programming-thoughts@1.0.0 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.kyEH8/_logs/2022-06-01T13_22_35_447Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 0ed2f2c60be2b2e793461388e2f4250b1e358bcc
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 0ed2f2c60be2b2e793461388e2f4250b1e358bcc
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to ancient-sea-47898.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/ancient-sea-47898.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ancient-sea-47898.git'
```

Comment: You're running the build in Node 8, which is well out of support - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specify-the-version-of-node. I'm not sure how the proxy is expected to fit into it.

Comment: I tried with node 16, but I get the same error